# URI is not registered (Settings | Languages & Frameworks | Schemas and DTDs)

Tags: android-studio

Hola he visto alguna pregunta sobre algo parecido, pero no creo que se trate de lo mismo.

Es algo extraño, al menos para mi, me esta mostrando un error en el siguiente Layaut

activity_main.xml

Pero lo raro es que este xml está dentro de la carpeta Layaut, pero que a su vez está dentro de la carpeta **drawable**

El árbol de carpetas lo estoy visualizando en modo Protect, y todos los Layaut que están en esa carpeta muestran errores.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En cambio sí lo pongo en modo Android, ya no aparece la carpeta Layaut dentro de la carpeta **drawable**, pero si sigue mostrando el error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si intento conectarme, para ver si el error desaparece, no llega a conectarse.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se si tiene algo que ver con subir la API

minSdkVersion 27
targetSdkVersion 29

Yo no he creado esa carpeta ahí, porque aparece dentro del la carpeta drawable?

Y como quitar eliminar esos errores ?

Gracias.

Comment: Encontrastes solution ? Eres de Tenerife ?

Comment: no Aksha, me puse a borrar archivos, no se como pasaron a esa carpeta, ahora sigo con otros problemas que he publicado en otros post, que por mas que he revisado otros comentarios, tampoco se porque me pasan, a ver si hay suerte y con el tiempo alguien me puede echar una mano, aunque sea al cuello, jeje